# dplyr: mutate with data from last column

Tags: r, dplyr, mutate

I want to create a new column with data from the last column of a data frame:

```
df <- matrix(1:4, ncol = 2) %>% as.data.frame()
df %>% mutate(V3 = .[[ncol(.)]] * 2)
```

Is there an easier to read and understand expression than `.[[ncol(.)]]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `across` and `last_col` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)

df <- matrix(1:4, ncol = 2) %>% as.data.frame()

df %>% 
  mutate(across(last_col(), ~ .x * 2, .names = "V3"))
#>   V1 V2 V3
#> 1  1  3  6
#> 2  2  4  8
```

Answer (score 2):

If using `dplyr::mutate()` is not a must, you could directly assign `V3` after reversing the column order:

```
df <- matrix(1:4, ncol = 2) %>% as.data.frame()
df$V3 <- 2*rev(df)[[1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers above are more efficient but out of completeness, you can assign the last column name to a string then reference the name in the mutate function.

If you want to offset from the last column (eg. second to last column) you can insert the offset position in `last_col()` argument like `last_col(1)`

```
library(dplyr)

df <- matrix(1:4, ncol = 2) %>% as.data.frame()

last_col <- df |> select(last_col()) |> names()
  
df |> 
mutate(V3=.data[[last_col]]*2)
```